# Webfont in public folder is not accessible in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I need your help with my problem. I just cloned a project from github to my localhost. I changed the `.htaccess` file to this one:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|fonts|images|slick)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

The folder structure is this:

`public
    |_  css
    |_  fonts
      |_ fontawesome-webfont.eot
      |_ fontawesome-webfont.ttf
      |_ fontawesome-webfont.svg
      |_ fontawesome-webfont.woff2
    |_  images
    |_  slick
    |_  js`

The css, images, js, and slick folders is okay but the contents of the fonts folder is not accessible.

I got this error:

`x GET http://localhost:88/portal/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0`
The file cannot be found.

When I tried to put files (just for testing) I put css file in `fonts` folder, the file can be read but not the webfont files.
But if I do it like this in the address bar:

`http://localhost:88/portal/public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0`, the file is accessible.

Do you have any idea on why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

your rule is correct [look here](http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=5d7bff15-781b-53b8-9173-604c8dc3a52a).
It might be a problem with your font files permissions . Make sure thay have 644 permission :

```
$ sudo chmod 644 <PATH_TO_FONTS_FOLDER>/*
```